# Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'. TS can't distinguish

Tags: typescript

Here, I want to create a function that can define its dependencies, and those dependencies are provided to the function on instantiation. I can't get TS to give the correct type checking here. The error I'm getting is:

```
(parameter) d1: string | number
Argument of type 'string | number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'
```

How to get TS to understand the types of the args in order without lumping them together as a union?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSA7AVsAxjAQwCMAbYAHgBU4BeOAjRAPlrgG8AoOOAE2BQx8MuAJbAAzgC502PIVLAA2gF0A3FzgBzYDGkAKAJS0WABSgQAtiPEVqAHzgYAriRJN1AX3UdQkWAmRUAEFxRGEAMQJ8aERwjCoAGjgAEX5xOFAYYEF0hkQVVjyVFjo9ADoKgihNKXZFAGk4EQw4AGtgRAgAMxS05WlUsHEG5QyQLJyZHHxiMnJmruAoOABVFgB%20VbhpDGAANyWPIxpTcysbKncOH3BoeC6nYRgRCBbm6fk5yiTB9MzsnjpTAfWYUPJMYp6DQEUIRKIwGJxaQhMK4SLRKCxeLfXpDJgJDR8ARCUQSAZpVgFGFwR6tDAQADuLWpvwJBmkwLkoMu7A0UB0TigLTYHnoQNkMwUl081wA9LK4ABRAAaQQAsiYADKK664V7ieBEgCMrE43CJAOypNqKgJ3G0ujghmMcDMlmswDK-PEEBIBz0RoMBI8uv1hv4ACZTYT%20JbhGIbco7VodPpjqd3TYvRJff6AOQEPNBjghjh6jAGpoSz7AADyRA%20rHeXIUej0PCNSR4EfTrrOHuzPr9wD0PoswAAyks9iJcCOO12e0G4IpjV3I8oDN4Hk8Xi0x5Pp7P50adk4LEQlovpAaoM1NEYzXBy0PPSQIJp253eD3PEA)

```
export type Injectable<T = any> = {
  dependencies: Injectable[];
  get: () => Promise<T | null>;
};

export type AsyncFactoryFn<T, Deps extends any[] = any[]> = (...args: {[K in keyof Deps]: Deps[K] extends Injectable<infer U> ? U : never}) => Promise<T>;

export function injectable<T, Deps extends Injectable<any>[]>(
  asyncFactoryFn: AsyncFactoryFn<T, Deps>,
  dependencies: Deps = [] as unknown as Deps,
): Injectable<T> {
  return {} as Injectable<T>;
}

// EXAMPLE

const dep1 = {
  dependencies: [],
  get: () => Promise.resolve(1),
}

const dep2 = {
  dependencies: [],
  get: () => Promise.resolve('a'),
}

const injectableObject = injectable((d1, d2) => Promise.resolve(someService(d1, d2)), [dep1, dep2]);

function someService(d1: number, d2: string) {
  console.log(d1, d2);
}
```

Comment: All you're looking for here is for the compiler to infer a tuple type instead of an array type for `[dep1, dep2]`, right?  If so you could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKp48w).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Please write it up and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that when TypeScript encounters an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#array_literals) like `[dep1, dep2]`, the default behavior is for its type to be inferred as a plain [array type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-array-type) like `Array<typeof dep1 | typeof dep2>` without a known length or ordering.  This is often what people want, since arrays are mutable and you can change their contents.  But right now this isn't desirable; you would prefer the compiler to infer a [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) instead, like `[typeof dep1, typeof dep2]`.

There are different ways to accomplish this; you could use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), like `[dep1, dep2] as const`, but this requires the caller of `injectable()` to do something.

Another way to do this is to make the `dependencies` parameter have a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) like `readonly [...Deps]` instead of just `Deps`.  This doesn't do much to the *type*, but it gives a tuple *context* that helps with inference.  As mentioned in [microsoft/TypeScript#39094](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/39094), the pull request introducing variadic tuple types:

> When the contextual type of an array literal is a tuple type, a tuple type is inferred for the array literal. The type `[...T]`, where `T` is an array-like type parameter, can conveniently be used to indicate a preference for inference of tuple types.

So we can do this:

```
export function injectable<T, Deps extends Injectable<any>[]>(
  asyncFactoryFn: AsyncFactoryFn<T, Deps>,
  dependencies: readonly [...Deps] = [] as unknown as Deps,
): Injectable<T> {
  return {} as Injectable<T>;
}
```

where I've replaced `Deps` with `readonly [...Deps]` (note that a [`readonly` tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) is actually more accepting than a non-`readonly` one; `readonly X[]` is assignable to `X[]` but not vice versa).

And now you get the behavior you want:

```
const injectableObject = injectable(
  (d1, d2) => Promise.resolve(someService(d1, d2)), // okay
  //^ (parameter) d1: number
  //   ^  (parameter) d2: string
  [dep1, dep2]
);
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-3x8VhfNNpDtKBWk0DRFEdCd02UDgDG8Z5XneNoV3XTdt13B03w-FZ91AmBwIwTQjBdOBWwXcMSAgTQ9D3Xgp08IA)